# ¿Como lograr que Google muestre título del sitio en resultados?

Tags: web, diseño

Me explico, un sitio aparece en los resultados de búsqueda de Google. Aparece con el icono definido para favicon.
Hasta ahí bien, pero a la derecha aparece una línea con el nombre del dominio y debajo aparece la dirección URL. Ejemplo: en la imagen aparece example.com, pero en otros dominios veo que en lugar del dominio aparece el nombre del sitio: Youtube, Apple, Wikipedia, o el que sea.

[image: Ejemplo de resultado de búsqueda]

He revisado el código de las páginas buscando una etiqueta meta y no veo ninguna.
¿Alguien sabe porqué ocurre esto y como puede controlarse?

Answer (score 1):

Ese es el `title` de tu sitio. Lo que pongas ahí sale en los resultados de Google.

Yo lo he comprobado con Wordpress y con webs de código puro que he hecho.

Si buscas **pinteres** en Google y examinas los resultados, veras que siempre ponen de que país es ese "pinteres". Pinteres - España o Pinteres - Mexico, pues cuando ves el codigo fuente de cada dominio, ese es el `title` de cada web.

Para SOes es:

```html
<title>Stack Overflow en español</title>
```

Pero en cada pregunta cambian de title, eso hace que cuando buscas una pregunta o un termino, si el `title` contiene dicha búsqueda, entonces se vera reflejada en el titulo del resultado de Google.

---

En base a tu comentario y mejor comprensión de lo que necesitas he buscado y al final, como te lo había comentado antes, es el `sitename` y el `title` los que priman para Google.

Por ejemplo, en Wordpress el `sitename` o `blogname` (en la DB) [es el que aparece en los resultados](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/how-to-change-wordpress-site-title/). Para un sitio puro se pueden intentar algunas [funciones con Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names?hl=es) o entender [como es que Google genera esos títulos](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/210102786/i-want-to-change-name-of-my-website-on-google-search-results?hl=en).

Si buscas en Google **[site name for google results](https://www.google.com/)** puedes entender más de como poder llegar a lo que quieres.

Comment: No me he explicado. Si te fijas en la imagen, justo al lado del icono hay dos líneas , la de arriba es el dominio (example.com) y abajo la url. El título es lo que se ve en grande en azul (Como crear...). La cuestión es que en la mayoría de los resultados eso es un nombre no un dominio. En lo de pinteres mira la entrada correspondiente a Apple, verás el título de la página en azul grande, pero al lado del icono pone Apple (solo)

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. Por el momento solo tengo sitios que ya generan el **sitename**. Intentaré subir alguno de código puro para ver si puedo cambiar eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, a eso me refería. No había sido capaz de encontrarlo.  Por ahí puedo empezar a enterarme bien del tema. Gracias de nuevo.